Remove a value from a vec based on a reference to that value
I'm trying to write a method for a struct which has a Vec as a member. The function I'd like to write, remove_thing, should take a reference to an element of the Vec and remove it, leaving the rest in place.
I'm getting a borrow checker error, that I cannot borrow the Vec as mutable, because I have a borrow on the element as immutable. My expectation would be that there is still a valid way to express this, as I'm not actually mutating the interior element, just the containing Vec. But I could be wrong.
Here's a short reproduction:
struct Thing {
    name: String,
    data: String,
}

struct HasSomeThings {
    things: Vec<Thing>,
}

impl HasSomeThings {
    fn thing_by_name(&self, name: &str) -> Option<&Thing> {
        for t in self.things.iter() {
            if t.name == name {
                return Some(&t);
            }
        }
        None
    }

    // Is it impossible to implement this function? 
    // It seems having a reference to a Thing in the vector prevents 
    // you from removing it from that vector.    
    fn remove_thing(&mut self, thing: &Thing) {
        self.things.retain(|t| t.name != thing.name);
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Imagine this comes from reading a file somewhere
    let mut some_things = HasSomeThings {
        things: vec![
            Thing { name: "one".to_string(), data: "one data".to_string() },
            Thing { name: "two".to_string(), data: "two data".to_string() },
            Thing { name: "three".to_string(), data: "three data".to_string() },
        ]
    };
    
    // Imagine this comes from user input
    let name = "one";
    let one_thing = some_things.thing_by_name(name).unwrap();
    println!("{}", one_thing.data);
    
    some_things.remove_thing(one_thing);
}

Rust Playground Link
The error I'm seeing is:
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `some_things` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:44:5
   |
41 |     let one_thing = some_things.thing_by_name(name).unwrap();
   |                     ----------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
44 |     some_things.remove_thing(one_thing);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^------------^^^^^^^^^^^
   |     |           |
   |     |           immutable borrow later used by call
   |     mutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 1 previous error

Is there some trick I can do to implement the remove_thing function? Or is there a reasonable way to restructure my code so that I can both work with a reference to the element from the Vec and then later remove it? Do I just need to rebuild the whole HasSomeThings instance from scratch?

This is one the rare cases where raw pointers are of use without involving any unsafe code:
// References coerce into pointers, so no other code needs to change.
fn remove_thing(&mut self, thing: *const Thing) {
    self.things.retain(|t| !std::ptr::addr_eq(t, thing));
}

playground

Wow, this is great news! Do you know of a good resource that could help me understand more about why / how this works?

Here's a way that doesn't use retain, so that you don't have to loop over the whole Vec every time. This still has time complexity of O(self.things.len()) because it moves the same number of elements, but it should be much faster.
/// Returns `false` if `thing` was not part of `self`.
pub fn remove_thing(&mut self, thing: *const Thing) -> bool {
    let start = self.things.as_ptr();
    let byte_diff = thing as isize - start as isize;
    let index = byte_diff / std::mem::size_of::<Thing>() as isize;
    if index < 0 || index as usize >= self.things.len() {
        // the item is not in `things`
        return false;
    }
    if byte_diff % std::mem::size_of::<Thing>() as isize != 0 {
        // This only happens if `thing` is not a valid pointer to `Thing`,
        // which may or may not be important to you.
        return false;
    }

    self.things.remove(index as usize);
    true
}

This may remove an element that wasn't used to create the pointer if that pointer was modified or is dangling.

And of course this can be made O(1) by using swap_remove if order doesn't matter.
